# Selecting Axis inside a tab group with a programmatic GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, tabs

When creating a GUI using OOP in MATLAB, I am having troubles understanding how to control which Axis of which Tab I want to plot my data in. I attach sample code to aid with my questions

1. First of all, when the GUI is loaded, only Axis 2 under Tab 2 is titled (Axis 2), the code `title('Axis 1');` does not seem to get through. Why is this?
2. When the code is run, by default there are no plots in Tab1 or Tab2. If you click "Plot Data" while Tab1 is open, then switch to Tab2, you can see the sine curve is plot in Tab2. But according to my code, or at leaste what I am trying to do, is that the sine curve should appear in Axis1 of Tab1.
3. But when you click on Tab2, and click 'Plot Data', the curve changes to the exponential, which is what I am expecting.

I am still quite new at OOP GUI with MATLA so there might be some simple stuff I am missing. Thanks for any help and comments.

```
classdef example < handle

    properties
        Figure;
        TabGroupAxis;
        TabsAxis;
        Axis1;
        Axis2;

        ButtonPlotData;

        DataToPlot;
    end

    methods
        function obj = example()
            create(obj)
            makeUpData(obj);
        end

        function create(obj)
            obj.Figure = figure('Position',[300 300 640 640]);

            obj.TabGroupAxis = uitabgroup(obj.Figure,'Units','pixels','Position',[100 20 600 600]);
            obj.TabsAxis(1) = uitab(obj.TabGroupAxis,'Title','Tab1');
            obj.TabsAxis(2) = uitab(obj.TabGroupAxis,'Title','Tab2');

            obj.Axis1 = axes('Parent',obj.TabsAxis(1),'Units','pixels','Position',[30 20 500 500]);
            obj.Axis2 = axes('Parent',obj.TabsAxis(2),'Units','pixels','Position',[30 20 500 500]);

            obj.ButtonPlotData = uicontrol(obj.Figure,'Style','pushbutton','String','Plot Data',...
                'Callback',@obj.buttonPlotDataCallback);

            axis(obj.Axis1);
            title('Axis 1');

            axis(obj.Axis2);
            title('Axis 2');
        end

        function makeUpData(obj)
            obj.DataToPlot(1).x = linspace(0,2*pi);
            obj.DataToPlot(1).y = sin(obj.DataToPlot(1).x);

            obj.DataToPlot(2).x = linspace(0,2*pi);
            obj.DataToPlot(2).y = exp(obj.DataToPlot(1).x);
        end

        function buttonPlotDataCallback(obj,hObject,eventdata)
            activeTab = obj.TabGroupAxis.SelectedTab.Title;

            switch activeTab
                case 'Tab1'
                    axis(obj.Axis1);
                    plot(obj.DataToPlot(1).x,obj.DataToPlot(1).y);
                case 'Tab2'
                    axis(obj.Axis2);
                    plot(obj.DataToPlot(2).x,obj.DataToPlot(2).y);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Long Answer**

Excellent question, your example made it really easy for me to understand the problem. I put a break point in the buttonPlotDataCallback and saw that the switch case is operation correctly, the problem was that `axis(obj.Axis1)` didn't change the focus. Looking at the documentation, that's because that isn't the correct use of `axis`.

An alternative way to plot the function is to use an overloaded method of plot

```
case 'Tab1'
    plot(obj.Axis1,obj.DataToPlot(1).x,obj.DataToPlot(1).y);
```

Now we realize that the reason that axis1 is not getting titled is that the call to axis on line 34 is not working either. This can also be fixed by overloading, this time `title`.

```
title(obj.Axis1,'Axis 1');
```

**Shorter Answer**

Turns out `axes` does exactly what you are using `axis` for. You have a typo that didn't get caught because `axis` is a valid function. change `axis(< handle >)` to `axes(< handle >)` and you'll be good to go.